# After calling SetTimer to start a new timer, am I safe to call KillTimer within that timer's TimerProc?

Tags: c, winapi, timer

For example, say I have the following `TimerProc`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#define IDT_TIMER1 1001
BOOL g_fKillTimer = FALSE;

VOID DoTimerTask(); // Among other things, sets the flag `g_fKillTimer` when needed

// Timer is started elsewhere with a call to: 
//  SetTimer(hWnd, IDT_TIMER1, 10000, TimerProc);
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(
    _In_ HWND hWnd,
    _In_ UINT uMsg,
    _In_ UINT_PTR idEvent,
    _In_ DWORD dwTime
)
{
    if (TRUE == g_fKillTimer)
    {
        KillTimer(hWnd, IDT_TIMER1);
        g_fKillTimer = FALSE;
    }
    DoTimerTask();
}
```

Is this code going to successfully kill the timer `IDT_TIMER1`? Or is the fact that I'm calling `KillTimer` within the timer procedure itself potentially going to present a problem for this? Will the function `DoTimerTask()` still be called?

Comment: The `TimerProc` callback is called on the same thread that installed the timer, so it's safe to call. Like any other non-throwing function, execution continues on the next statement. However, if you're setting a timer with a timer callback, the timer ID is assigned at runtime. You cannot use a compile time constant to identify the timer.

Comment: It's explained in the *Return value* paragraph: *"If the function succeeds and the `hWnd` parameter is `NULL`, the return value is an integer identifying the new timer. An application can pass this value to the `KillTimer` function to destroy the timer."*

Comment: But, the `hWnd` parameter is *not* null in my case. What does that have to do with the presence of the callback function anyway?

Comment: Yeah, timer IDs are only auto-assigned if hWnd is null (i.e. for thread timers). Presence or otherwise of a callback function doesn't affect it.

Comment: *"What does that have to do with the presence of the callback function anyway?"* - Just my mental model of how those timers work, which precluded me from seeing the possibility that you can pass both a callback and a window handle. Which seems like an odd choice. If you are the implementer of a window class, you can handle `WM_TIMER` messages right from the window procedure. If you aren't the implementer of a class then you run into ID collision issues, when setting up a per-window timer. The only safe option here is to install a thread timer (i.e. passing a `NULL` window handle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this code going to successfully kill the timer `IDT_TIMER1`?

Yes.

> is the fact that I'm calling `KillTimer` within the timer procedure itself potentially going to present a problem for this?

No.  It is perfectly safe to call `KillTimer` inside the timer callback.

> Will the function `DoTimerTask()` still be called?

Yes, since you are not `return`'ing from the callback before calling `DoTimerTask()` again, eg:

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(
    _In_ HWND hWnd,
    _In_ UINT uMsg,
    _In_ UINT_PTR idEvent,
    _In_ DWORD dwTime
)
{
    if (TRUE == g_fKillTimer)
    {
        KillTimer(hWnd, IDT_TIMER1);
        g_fKillTimer = FALSE;
        return; // <-- HERE
    }
    DoTimerTask();
}
```